# Primality of $2^n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that $2^n - 1$ is a prime if and only if n is a prime?

Comment: Can $2^{a \cdot b} -1$ be prime?

Comment: These are called Mersenne Primes. It is also true that if $n$ is composite, then $2^n-1$ is also composite.

Comment: If this were the case, we would not have to search for new Mersenne primes. But what is true is that $2^n-1$ can only be prime if $n$ is prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime. This is because, if $d|n$, then $2^d-1|2^n-1$.

However, there are prime $n$ such that $2^n-1$ isn’t prime. In particular, $2^{11}-1=23 \cdot 89$.

Answer (score 5):

Only if, yes, since if $a>1$ is a proper factor of $n$ then $2^a-1|2^n-1$. The converse fails as $2^{11}-1=23\times89$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I just found a counter evidence. 2^11 - 1 is not a prime.